# Как добавить картинку в сообщение бота телеграмм, не сохраняя её локально?

Tags: python-3.x, telebot, urllib

Доброе время суток! у меня есть URL картинки, которую бот должен отправить сообщением. как отправить картинку, не сохраняя её локально?

у меня есть такой код, но он сохраняет локально, а у меня много картинок, и памяти может не хватить, поэтому и задаю вопрос...

P.S: использовать облачное хранилище для картинок тоже не могу...

```
import telebot
import time
import urllib


TOKEN = 'BOT_TOKEN'
url='URL_jpg'
f = open('out.jpg','wb')
f.write(urllib.request.urlopen(url).read())
f.close()

tb = telebot.TeleBot(TOKEN)


@tb.message_handler(commands=['photo'])
def send_photo(message):
    tb.send_chat_action(message.chat.id, 'upload_photo')
    img = open('out.jpg', 'rb')
    tb.send_photo(message.chat.id, img, reply_to_message_id=message.message_id)
    img.close()

tb.polling()

while True:
    time.sleep(0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё просто!

```
url='URL_jpg'
tb.send_photo(message.chat.id, photo=url)
```